# How to interpret light and photon?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

I've been trying to solidify my understanding on properties of light and this is what my understanding is so far:

Light is an EM wave that travels in a constant speed C.
Light has a quantized energy and momentum called Photon which can only be determined when measured.

Although light travels and behaves like a wave before we make any measurement (position, momentum, energy), once we make a measurement its position, momentum and energy is only measured at a specific point with specific value.

Am I understanding the properties of light correctly?

Comment: EM waves travels in a constant speed 'c' only through vacuum.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Right. I guess I should've specified that I was only talking about an ideal case where it's vacuum.

Comment: light tends to travel in straight lines ... unless there is an object to cause diffraction or refraction or reflection ....

Comment: the light wavelength corresponds to the energy gap that the electron jumps in an atom molecule.  All photons are created by electrons .... all photons all eventually absorbed by electrons in atoms/molecules.

Comment: light is usually considered as the visible part of the em spectrum .... but the em spectrum has many other wavelengths from short cosmic rays / x-rays  to very long radio waves.

Comment: em waves can superimpose ... i.e. they can cross paths without having any effect whatsoever on each other.  If they align well enough to cancel each other the energy is conserved  in the em field and the photons reemerge eventually.  Photons never cancel each other.

Comment: each photons path is determined by the em field .... some paths a re preferred ... some not.  In the DSE there are no photons in the dark .... the light bands have all the photons.  The Feynman path integral can be used to calculate path probability.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Thanks for all these info! I guess I wasn't stating my question properly. What I wanted to know was how EM-wave travel and give off energy and momentum. My understanding is that EM-wave travels like a wave but it gives energy and momentum like a particle. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct ..... but a wave can give energy and momentum just like a particle.  The ancient discussion about whether light is a wave or a particle is very very old and boring! The light wave is very special ... is it very local (in a small space) when absorbed/observed .... so using particle model is ok in many experiments ..... but particle model is not OK in many other experiments.